# If classical EM-waves of X wavelength have photons of X wavelength, why is there current in the receiver during the wave creation?

Tags: electromagnetism, photons

As the title states. I've had it explained to me that an antenna that's emitting e.g. 1khz yields 1khz photons.

So let's emit one 1khz wave (emitter). If we place a conductor (receiver) nearby, we will under t=1/1000 second see the current raise and drop inside the receiver.

We're assuming that there's a high photon intensity.

It is possible that I'm misusing the definition of photon, for which I assume is this: 1 packet of energy that gets absorbed in one go by atoms or electrons, the absorption is what's causing an effect in the receiver. The packet/photon is also created in one go, instantaneously.

The emitter must during this t second, from s=0 to s=t be emitting lots of photons describing the state of the emitter. My argument for that is that the receiver can't deduce the future, e.g. if the photons stop at s=t/2, how should the receiver know that the sender from there on haven't change its current in a specific way? So the photons describe what's happening at the emitter.

But if we are sending photons during time s=0 to s=t, and it isn't known yet exactly what the sender will do at for example s=t/3, how can those earlier photons describe or be 1khz photons? The sender could for example at s=t/4 decide to finish the wave as a 2khz wave or something, just change its mind in the middle of the 1khz wave (although it won't be perfectly shaped), then those first 1khz photons would be wrong.

Now if we instead are assuming that the sender is sending those 1khz photons at s=t (1 wave finished), after one oscillation, billions of them at the same time, how can the current in the receiver already have begun?

One solution I can think of is this: the emitter sends 1khz photons, but photons that describe different states of the 1khz wave. It would then be sending the slope of the wave where the slope itself only can be concluded to belong to a certain wavelength. But there must be some more information in there too then, since a given slope fits all possible waves in progress.

At what time between s=0 and s=t is the 1khz photon emitted? And again, if it's emitted before the wave has finished: we got problems, it's looking into the future, or it's guessing! If AFTER the wave is done oscillating in the sender: why are we having induced current in the receiver at s=t/4?

Comment: Well thought. Some additional points see https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/199692/what-is-an-em-wave/199714#199714